# What's the difference between declaring let for a Struct but declaring var for its properties and vice versa?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

As subject, what's the difference between a and b?

```
struct A {
  var x: Int
}
struct B {
  let x: Int
}
let a = A(x: 1)
var b = B(x: 1)
```

Please also explain the impact in term of functional programming. which one i should use to create an immutable object for the sake of FP?

Comment: `let` and `var` affect (and *only* affect) the variable/member they immediately precede.

Answer (score 2):

With `a`, you can't change `a.x`, because you can't mutate through a `let` reference to a value type (such as a struct). If you had said `var` instead of `let`, you could.

With `b`, you can't change `b.x`, because `b.x` is a constant. Saying `var` didn't matter here; it is `x` *itself* that is constant. Even code inside B can't change `x`.

Comment: And `b` can be assigned another instance of `B`, but `a` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

To summarize

**a :** Once this is set, regardless of the mutability of the contents of the structure you can't do anything with it other than read.  The highest level of immutability restricts this.

**Application?**  Maybe it takes a few passes to get the structure's values setup but once done you want to lock it down and reference the immutable finished version. This is somewhat memory efficient although I don't know how it handles the mutable "var" within the struct even though it is immutable.

**b :** You can only replace the structure, but you can't change the value within the structure.

**Application?**  Once setup, you don't want the value to change however you want to be able to completely replace the structure at a later time.

**c:** (See below code for this example) You can change the value within the structure, and you can completely replace the structure so long as the type of the variable (which is now strongly typed to structure "C") is also typed to structure "C".  This gives the most freedom but is likely less memory friendly since it is mutable through and through.

**Application?**  you want to be able to change the values within, or simply replace the whole structure with another identically typed structure.  highly flexible.

Hope this helps.

Here is some playground code.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play


struct A {
    var x: Int
}
let a = A(x: 1)
let d = A(x: 5)



struct B {
    let x: Int
}
var b = B(x: 1)
var e = B(x: 5)




struct C {
    var x: Int
}
var c = C(x: 1)
var f = C(x: 7)


// --- A ---- /

//can we change the value of a.x?
//Nope. The "Let" for "a' locks this down.  Structure and its values are locked in
//a.x = 4

//can we replace a's value with "B" since it is the structurally similar and because it is a Var?
//Nope.  "a" is now typed to "A" and requires a structure of "A".
//a = B(x: 1)

//Can I replace "a" with exactly the same structure?
//Nope. it is assigned to a constant (let) which means the WHOLE structure is locked down.
//a = d



// --- B ---- /
//can we change the value of b.x?
//Nope.  The value in the parameter is locked down with an inner constant (let).
//b.x = 7

//can we replace b's value with "A" since it is the structurally similar and because it is a Var?
//Nope.  "b" is now strongly typed to "B" and requires a structure of "B".
//b = A(x: 1)

//Can I replace "b" with exactly the same structure?
//YES. You can change the entire value of b so long as it has a strongly typed contents of "B".
b = e


// --- C ---- /


//Can we change the value of c.x?  
//YES!  Both levels are mutable so it can be changed.
c.x = 4

//can we replace c's value with "A" since it is the structurally similar and because it is a Var?
//Nope.  "c" is still strongly typed to structure "C" and requires an identical structure.
//c = B(x: 1)


//Can I replace "C" with exactly the same structure?
//YES. You can change the entire value of "c" so long as it has a strongly typed contents of "C".
c = f
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question....

Since there are varying limitations depending on how you set up the structure and variable, what is best is going to be dependent less on what is a "better" method and more on what you actually need it to do.

Of course, from an efficiency perspective, Apple frequently states that using a constant (let) whenever possible is better for memory management.  Frankly, since "a" locks everything down, if you want to be completely efficient and you're not going to change anything once you set the variable with the structure in it, you would want to do something like below.

```
struct Z {
    let x: Int
}
let z = Z(x: 1)
```

You can't do do anything but read "z" and "a" after the variable is set.

So based on Apple's recommendations, "z" would probably be a better practice purely for memory management sake.